# How do you resolve a docker alias using node?

Tags: node.js, docker

Say you have two environments in your node app: local, and docker.

If you want to run the app in local you will run it with

```
env=local node app.js
```

And if you want to run it in a docker container you would do

```
env=docker node app.js
```

Your node app connects to a simple database. You link the name of the database to something eg. "database-server". How do you figure out what this ip address is in your app to store it in a variable? 
I imagine

```
console.log(database-server)
```

will return "database-server not defined"
I basically want some code similar to:

```
If(process.env.env === "docker") {process.env.database-ip = database-server} 
Else {process.env.database-ip = localhost}
```

Except with this code database-server will be undefined.

I understand db.connect(database-server:port) will generally autoresolve the ip address. But my app connects to the database in multiple files

docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3'

services:
  myapp:
        build: .
        container_name: "myapp"
        links:
            - mongoserver
            - ipfs
        depends_on:
            - mongoserver
            - ipfs
        environment:
          - ENV=docker-dev
  mongoserver:
    image: 'mongo:3.7.9'
    container_name: "mongodb"
    ports:
      - '27017:27017'
    volumes:
      - 'data-volume:/data/db'
  ipfs:
    image: 'jbenet/go-ipfs:latest'
    container_name: "ipfs"
    ports:
     - "5001:5001"
     - "4001:4001"
     - "8080:8080"

volumes:
  data-volume:
```

Dockerfile in root directory

```
FROM node

RUN mkdir -p /usr/src/app
ADD server.js /usr/src/app
ADD package.json /usr/src/app
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

# install the dependencies from the package.json file
RUN npm install

EXPOSE 9000
CMD [ "node", "/usr/src/app/server.js" ]
```

***TL:DR how do you store a docker network alias in a variable?***

Comment: Is your database also running in docker? Are you using docker-compose?

Comment: I am using docker-compose, yes. My database is also running in docker. Kinda close to giving up and using hardcoded static ip addresses.

Comment: Can you post your docker-compose file?

Comment: Sure. Do you also need the dockerfile for myApp?

Comment: No I don't think so. I posted an answer, let me know if it works out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Docker aliases are resolved through local dns. Therefore most of the time you don't need to resolve them.

Answer (score 0):

I think You need loading of config depending on environment.

1) Dockerfile:

```
FROM node:8-alpine
ARG EXPOSE=5005
ENV PORT $EXPOSE
ENV EXPOSE_PORT $EXPOSE
EXPOSE $EXPOSE_PORT
RUN apk add --no-cache curl
ADD ./ /app
WORKDIR /app
RUN npm i
CMD ["npm", "start"]
```

2) start script in package.json file:

```
"start": "NODE_ENV=production node server.js",
"development": "NODE_ENV=development node server.js",
```

3) config folder with multiple environment configs:

[image: config folder]

4) `index.js` that detects `NODE_ENV` and loads necessary json and replaces `PORT` (see last lines) and etc external variables:

```
'use strict';

const nconf = require('nconf');
const path = require('path');
const fs = require('fs');

nconf.env().argv();

const environments = [
  'development',
  'production',
  'local',
  'test'
];

if (!nconf.get('NODE_ENV')) {
  throw new Error('NODE_ENV parameter not defined! \nPlease consider to use one of these environments: ' + environments.join(', '));
}

if (environments.indexOf(nconf.get('NODE_ENV')) < 0) {
  throw new Error('NODE_ENV parameter is not valid! \nPlease consider to use one of these environments: ' + environments.join(', '));
}

try {
  const envConfigFileName = 'config.' + nconf.get('NODE_ENV') + '.json';
  const configFile = path.join(__dirname, envConfigFileName);
  const hiddenConfigFile = path.join(__dirname, '.' + envConfigFileName);
  let currentConfigFile = configFile;

  if (!fs.existsSync(configFile)) {
    if (!fs.existsSync(hiddenConfigFile)) {
      throw new Error('Cannot locate ' + nconf.get('NODE_ENV') + ' environment configuration file');
    }
    currentConfigFile = hiddenConfigFile;
    console.log('\n\n');
    console.log('WARNING READING HIDDEN (dot-file) CONFIG FILE: ' + hiddenConfigFile);
    console.log('MAKE SURE TO HAVE LOCAL COPY OF IT WITHOUT dot (.) SYMBOL AS PREFIX IN FILE NAME');
    console.log('\n\n');
  }

  nconf.file(currentConfigFile);
} catch (exception) {
  throw new Error(exception);
}

if (process.env.PORT) nconf.set('app:http:port', process.env.PORT);
if (process.env.HOST) nconf.set('app:http:host', process.env.HOST);
if (process.env.HTTPS_PORT) nconf.set('app:https:port', process.env.HTTPS_PORT);
if (process.env.HTTPS_HOST) nconf.set('app:https:host', process.env.HTTPS_HOST);

process.env.NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED = 0;
// if(nconf.get('NODE_ENV') !== 'production') process.env.NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED = 0;

module.exports = nconf;
```

5) example usage of config module in `app.js` :

```
const config = require('./config');

consd db = require('./database');
db.connect(config.get('db:uri'));

const express = require('express');
const app = express();
app.get('/', (req, res) => res.status(204).send());

const listenHost = config.get('app:http:host');
const listenPort = config.get('app:http:port');
const httpServer = http.createServer(app);

httpServer.listen(listenPort, listenHost,
  () => logger.info('App listening at http://%s:%s', listenHost, listenPort));
```

Comment: I don't get it. I might just be slow. I think in your case you're running a single docker container and then setting the environment variables manually. For me I'm trying to let docker create the links automatically.

Comment: My example is overall definition how PORT is passed from Dockerfile, how config is loaded depending on environment and etc

Comment: I see. What if you're passing the port at runtime? Eg. docker run --link

Comment: in my version gitlab-ci.yml passes port if it's not being passed it takes default 5005 as You see

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using docker-compose and `links` inside of it, you can access any of the other services by their service name. For example, your database, you can do `db.connect('mongoserver:27017')` and docker will resolve mongoserver into it's actual IP.

You should be able to access the 'mongoserver' in any of your files where it expects some type of hostname, IP address, etc. in your node.js app. Please let me know if this works out.

Comment: This does work. But I was aware this worked. Thanks anyways.

The issue is I'm working with legacy code that I don't want to change too much and a lot of the time the ip address is stored in a variable. So I want to store the ip address in a variable.